# Execution order of buy / sell orders

Tags: pine-script

So I wrote a study which sends buy / sell signals.

I converted this study into a strategy for backtesting.

Imagine I get the following signals:

`B1 => B2 => B3 => S1 => S2 => S3`

Now I want to sell in the following order:

```
B3 => S1 // S1 sells what was bought on B3
B2 => S2 // S2 sells what was bought on B2
B1 => S3 // S3 sells what was bought on B1
```

Like in math where the first opening brace is closed last.

How can I tell Pine Script to execute sell orders like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default TV backtester closes entries in FIFO manner. If you want LIFO, use this:

```
...
strategy(..., close_entries_rule = "ANY")
...
```

Comment: Yes, and that is exactly NOT the behavior I want, I rather want LIFO manner.